# import declarations may only appear at top level of a module when already at the top

Tags: javascript, angular, importerror

I have a project that looks like this:

```
website/
    js/
        modules/
            axios.min.js
        app.js
        factory.js
    app.js
```

For some reason, there are two `app.js` files (the project is not mine, I'm just working on it right now) and both of them look exactly the same. This project is a frontend for an application, and it's written on AngularJS.

I need to include axios in this project for some stuff, so I placed the `axios.min.js` file inside the modules folder (as I was told to do, because this is not a node project and we coudln't just `npm install axios`) and now I'm trying to import it to the correct place.

Here are some snippets of the files in question:

`website/app.js` and `website/js/app.js`:

```
var App = angular.module('App', ['ngResource', 'ui.router', "pascalprecht.translate", "ngSanitize", 'angular-loading-bar', 'oc.lazyLoad', 'smart-table', 'angular-growl', 'ngAnimate', 'ngMask', 'ngFileUpload'])
App.constant("URL_BASE", "http://localhost/php/");
App.constant("NUM_PAGE", "10");
App.constant("ESPANOL", true);
App.constant("INGLES", false);
App.constant("FRANCES", false);

//App.constant("URL_BASE", "https://activities.domain.com/php/");
//App.constant("URL_BASE", "localhost/php/");
App.run(function ($rootScope, ESPANOL, INGLES, FRANCES)
{
    // stuff
});
```

`website/js/factory.js`:

```
App
    .factory('Api', function () {
        return {
            getTracks: function () {
                
            }
        }
    })
```

Now that this is all laid out, here's my problem:

I need to use axios inside the `getTracks` function. At first, I tried putting `import {axios} from "./modules/axios";` at the start of the file, but that got me an error saying `import declarations may only appear at top level of a module`. So my next thought was to have axios inside a constant in the App, that the function would gain access through the factory function. So I moved the import declaration to `website/app.js`, like this:

```
var App = angular.module('App', ['ngResource', 'ui.router', "pascalprecht.translate", "ngSanitize", 'angular-loading-bar', 'oc.lazyLoad', 'smart-table', 'angular-growl', 'ngAnimate', 'ngMask', 'ngFileUpload'])
App.constant("URL_BASE", "http://localhost/php/");
App.constant("NUM_PAGE", "10");
App.constant("ESPANOL", true);
App.constant("INGLES", false);
App.constant("FRANCES", false);
import {axios} from "./js/modules/axios";
App.constant("axios", axios);

App.run(function ($rootScope, ESPANOL, INGLES, FRANCES)
{
    // stuff
}
```

And that works, it imports axios correctly and stores it in that constant. However, when I modified the factory function like below to access axios, I got an Unkown Provider error:

```
    .factory('Api', function (axios) {
        return {
            getTracks: function () {
                // just to test
                axios.get('google.com').then(response => {console.log(response)});
            }
        }
    })
```

So then I started tinkering with the whole project changing small bits back and forth until I figured out that the constants in `website/app.js` mean nothing, and that the constants in `website/js/app.js` are the ones I'm getting in the factory function. So I just moved the import there, but that gets me the `import declarations may only appear at top level of a module` error again. I can't get rid of `website/app.js`, and I can't find a way to get axios to be a constant in the App declared in `website/js/app.js` so I'm completely lost here.

It's also worth mentioning that I've never worked with angular before, and that I have very little experience with front end development (I'm only working on this because I have to set up some API calls), and since this is an old, *old* project I've been assigned to work on, the documentation does not help a single bit and looks nothing like what I have here.

In conclusion, I need to use `axios` in `website/js/factory.js`, and I **need** to import it somewhere from `website/js/modules/`, using the `import` keyword, because `require` is apparently not a thing.

Edit: Also, better suggestions for the title of this post are welcome, I could not think of anything short but descriptive

Comment: _"I need to use axios..."_ - Do you really? Why not `fetch()`?

Comment: @Andreas yeah sorry, I just wrote that fast and then forgot to edit it out. I need to use `axios` because that's what I've been told to use :P

Comment: IMHO: It's not in the app yet so there was no need so far. You should ask them what that library is supposed to solve that cannot be solved with `fetch()` for free. You don't need axios just to grab some JSON from an API.

Comment: @Andreas. It doesn't just fetch JSON (that's just that specific function), the API is used to control some devices, and I suppose axios was chosen because it seems cleaner or easier to use an maintain. If I could choose I would rewrite everything from scratch, this project is ugly and really not that big, but I've already convinced them to rewrite the backend, so I don't know if I can get away with more

Comment: AngularJS has built-in module called `$http` and usually it's used for all operations